# sms is not reaching on other device while sending through SMS Manager

Tags: java, android, sms

I am trying to send sms fom my android mobile to another mobile using SMS Manager. Code is working fine , no error. But when I tested after sending the sms , sms has not reached on other device.I search a lot about this but got no solution. Also  I have dual sim..is there any issue with it....?
Following is my code

```
public  void test(View v)
{
    askPermission();

try {

String phoneNumber = "1234567890";
String message = "This sms is sent by Meenakshi ";
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
//ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);

Toast.makeText(birthday_wish.this, "Message Sent",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(birthday_wish.this, "Message not Sent",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}

private void askPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},1);
}
```

In manifest -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-
permission>
```

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: I am not sure but the issue may be with the provider, can you able to try with some other service providers SIM.

Comment: I tested your code. It works fine. I send an sms to a complete number.. with international digits... like +112123456789 (international code, area code and number).... So, either is a carrier issue or you are sending to wrong number (not sending with number format expected by your carrier)

Comment: I am using jio SIM and my mobile is vivo v5.. and my android version is 6.0....is there any issue with anyone one of these??

Comment: After i have sent the msg...my message is showing that msg is not sent...retry...